# Apex unit test - Error on ContentDocumentId(Missing field)

Tags: unit-test, contentdocument

I'm practicing an apex unit test and getting an insert fail on **ContentDocumentId** and expecting a reconstruction. 
Any idea of this?

[image]

```
@isTest
public static void testUpdateResponse() {

  ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
  cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
  cv.Title = 'testCV1';
  cv.PathOnClient = 'testCV1';
  cv.IsMajorVersion = false;
  insert cv;

  ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink(); // HERE
  cdl.ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId;
  insert cdl;

  account b = new account();
  b.Name = 'myAccount2';
  insert b;

  saveBase64_File testA = new saveBase64_File();

  Map<String, Object> inputMap = new Map<String, Object>();
  inputMap.put('base64', 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
  inputMap.put('fileName', 'user_image_1');
  inputMap.put('accountId', b.id);
  inputMap.put('contentDocumentId', cdl.id);
  Map<String, Object> outputMap = new Map<String, Object>();

  testA.invokeMethod('updateImage', inputMap, outputMap, new Map<String, Object>());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem

```
 ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink(); // HERE
 cdl.ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId;
 insert cdl;
```

The `cv.ContentDocumentId` has to be queried for after you insert the ContentVersion.

```
insert cv;
cv = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion
                               WHERE Id = :cv.Id][0];
.. insert ContentDocumentLink here
```

Comment: Thanks @cropredy!